# How can I check if a udev rule fired?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, udev

I am trying to acquaint myself with [udev](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Udev), under [Ubuntu 13.10](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ubuntu_version_history#Ubuntu_13.10_.28Saucy_Salamander.29) (Saucy Salamander).

Here is my first simple *95.usbbackup.rules* rule:

```
ACTION=="add", SUBSYSTEMS="usb", RUN+="/usr/local/bin/my_backup.sh"
```

And here is the script (which has been [chmodded](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chmod) *+x*) *my_backup.sh*:

```
#!/bin/bash
touch /tmp/test
```

Nothing at all happens when I plug in external drives. How can I check (a log, a command, anything) if the rule fired?

Comment: I think you mean `SUBSYSTEMS=="usb"`. I.e. double `==` which tests for equality rather than single `=` which assigns a value to a key.

Comment: That rule (once fixed, see previous comment) would run for *every* USB device plugged into USB ports (mouse, camera, even turning on your monitor with integrated USB hub connected to pc!) What you probably want is a rule to trigger on `block` subsystem matching either `ENV{ID_FS_UUID}`, `ATTRS{serial}`, or `ATTRS{idVendor}`/`ATTRS{idProduct}`... If you really want to backup to any USB block device, match `ENV{ID_BUS}=="usb"`. Also keep in mind a rule that is too generic may run multiple times for a single device add, so you may want to match something else like `ENV{DEVTYPE}=="partition"` too.

Answer (score 19):

With udev / systemd version 241 and similar, as root:

```
udevadm control --log-priority=debug
journalctl -f
```

Or to make it permanent, again as root:

```
vi /etc/udev/udev.conf
# edit the log level as described in "man udev.conf"
systemctl restart systemd-udevd
journalctl -f
```

PS: the most frequent yet IMHO *wrong* answer looks like:

<strike>udevadm -d test /devices/where/is/my/device |& less</strike>

... but this has a number of issues. The main ones:

- `where/is/my/device` ? Tedious, complicated and error-prone.
- Comparing old answers to recent udev version 241 output, `udevadm test` seems to show less information that it used to.
- `udevadm -d test` **is only a simulation**! Every time it warns:

  This program is for debugging only, it does not run any program specified by a RUN key. It may show incorrect results, because some values may be different, or not available at a simulation run.

`udevadm test` is for developing a new rule, it's not for troubleshooting broken, missing or overridden rules.

Comment: It's `/etc/udev/udev.conf` not `/etc/udev/udevd.conf`

Comment: Thank you @cdleonard for the fix.

Comment: `vi /etc/udev/udev.conf` and then make what edits exactly? what should the *contents* of that config file be?

Comment: @tarabyte on my Linux system the `/etc/udev/udev.conf` is pre-existing and has instructions. I just edited the answer and added "edit the log level as described in man udev.conf"

Comment: What does the strikeout mean? That it is not incorrect?

Comment: @PeterMortensen: I believe the strike out is to make it clear that the command should **not** be used, for the reasons that MarcH details.

Answer (score 8):

`udevadm test $(udevadm info --query=path --name=device_name)` should tell you which commands *would* be executed on a device plug in, citing the `udev` rules involved. For instance:

```
# udevadm test /block/sdd
...
udev_rules_apply_to_event: PROGRAM '/sbin/multipath -c /dev/sdd' /lib/udev/rules.d/40-multipath.rules:11
...
```

Answer (score 7):

I'm pretty sure this should work. Reload your udev rules after editing your rules:

`udevadm control --reload-rules && udevadm trigger` as root.

Comment: I made a narrower rule : KERNEL=="sdb", which works. Does udev only treats rules that identify some hardware uniquely?

Comment: No, try `KERNEL!="sdz*"` and you should get everything (except sdz[1-9])

Comment: This doesn't really answer the question. How do you know if the rules triggered?

Comment: You know because the script is run. You can make it write to a logfile. Also `udevadm monitor`

Answer (score 5):

I'm running kernel 3.0.35, but the following works for me.

To get the path for the device you can do something like this:

```
udevadm info --name /dev/sda1 --query all
```

You will get more information than you need, but you're interested in the DEVPATH.

Then to see what udev rules are executed, you run this:

```
udevadm test DEVPATH
```

I don't think this actually executes the rules. The documentation says this 'simulates' the events for the given device.
To get more information, check out the [man page for udevadm](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/udevadm.html).

Answer (score 3):

One thing I ended up doing, on a system where I had somewhat limited ability to change stuff (enable debug, change logging, etc - I could do it but I would have to override some configuration management tools) is to simply run an additional command that log to /tmp. You can for example add a 2nd run command:

```
RUN+="/bin/sh -c 'echo $(date) $(env) >>/tmp/udev-debug.log'"
```

Add anything you like there, including *string substitutions* described in udev manpage. Make sure you append the log so you catch every udev invocation matching your rule (it may run multiple times for a single added device, which may or may not be what you want...)

Comment: This is very flexible and probably the right way to debug the rules.

Answer (score 2):

You can give a command as root like this:

> udevadm monitor

It will show when a rule has fired.

Comment: `udevadm monitor` just shows the udev events, but not if a corresponding rule was fired. However, you can look for the event which should trigger the rule, but then you do not know if your rule works.

Answer (score 0):

I was having the same problem with Raspberry Pi 3 B+. I was trying to invoke a script on inserting a USB storage device. The rules do not get logged in syslog, so it becomes very difficult to understand which rule worked or which rule failed.

So I did the following:

1. I made my rule file in /etc/udev/rules.d/100-myrule.rules
2. Then I ran the command `sudo /etc/init.d/udev restart`

and when I checked, it worked.

A piece of information, that may or may not be useful, is that the filesystems are readonly for udev until the command in step 2 is executed.

Comment: Why did you name the rule as `100-myrule.rules`? The rule is executed before any rules whose name start by "10-" or e.g. by "20-".